# Animate RecyclerView when deleting inserting a row?

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, android-recyclerview

In iOS when data changes, i.e. a record is being deleted, calling `UITableView`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method, will show a quick animation and that GUI row will dismiss at the end.

Is it any similar approach in Android? So I do not want just 'rerender' the `RecycleView`, but 'rerender' only certain rows, and show an 'insert' or 'delete', or 'update' animation on it.

Comment: Add your code please. Are you using adapter.remove() and adapter.notifyItemRemoved()?

Comment: if you use default item animator for recycler and call `notifyItemInserted()` or `notifyItemRemoved()` default animation is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Put this method inside your adapter.

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
    YOUR_LIST.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, YOUR_LIST.size());
}
```

and call `removeAt(POSITION_TO_REMOVE)` from where you want to perform delete operation.

It will remove view from RecycleView and animate with slideUp animation.